# how to select the last text from message table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (messages and user). I want to select the last (msg_id,text) from the messages table for a particular ad_id and need to select the name of the user from the user table.

```
SELECT u.id
     , m.date
     , m.ad_id
     , max(m.msg_id)as msg_id
     , u.first_name
     , m.text
     , m.u_to_id
     , m.u_from_id 
FROM user u 
JOIN messages m
  ON CASE WHEN m.u_from_id ='14' THEN u.id = m.u_to_id 
          ELSE u.id = m.u_from_id END 
 AND (m.u_from_id='14' OR m.u_to_id='14') 
 AND m.ad_id='20'  
GROUP BY CONCAT(m.ad_id,u.id)   
ORDER by m.msg_id DESC
```

this query is working but I can't select t the last m.text[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKvkI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id, m.text
FROM user u
JOIN messages m ON m.msg_id = (SELECT max(msg_id) FROM messages WHERE u_from_id = u.id)
```

I simplified your query to show the logic relevant to your question.  Basically you want to join your messages table on the msg_id that is equal to the inner query of the max msg_id with that user.

Comment: sorry to say.. the query result is not the expected one.                                                          I give         "ON CASE WHEN m.u_from_id ='14' THEN u.id=m.u_to_id ELSE u.id= m.u_from_id END" because the person with id='14' is reading the message so instead of selecting his name select the other persons name

Comment: GROUP BY CONCAT(m.ad_id,u.id)  is given because avoiding the existance of more than one message of a user on a particular ad_id.                               sorry for the confusions.

Answer (score 0):

After so many experiments added a new column(bargainer) for identify the recipient and this query working fine for me

```
select m.msg_id,m.text,m.status,m.date,m.bargainer,m.ad_id,u.first_name,u.id from user u    JOIN   messages m  where msg_id in (select max(msg_id) from messages m where m.ad_id=20 and u.id=m.bargainer group by(m.bargainer))group by(m.msg_id) order by msg_id DESC
```